# Display 1 image of subfolder

Tags: php

I would like to display one(first) image of multiple subfolders,
I've got this to display all files from all subfolders
other (better) solutions are also very welcome

```
$path = realpath('img/gallery');

$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($objects as $name => $object){
  $example = '/somestring/';
  $trimmed =  str_replace("/somestring/", "", $name);

  echo "<img src=".$trimmed." /></br>";
  //...
}
```

The gallery looks now like this

```
        foreach ($images as $img) { ?>
<ul class="list_4">
    <li>
        <div class="block_pic">
        <?php echo "<img src='$img' alt='whatever' /></br>"; ?>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
     <?php      }
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Current html

```
<ul class="list_4">
    <li>
        <div class="block_pic">
        <?php

        echo "<a href=".$trimmed."><img src=".$trimmed." alt=' '></a>";
        //echo "<img src=".$trimmed." />";
        ?>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify - you want to traverse recursively through `img/gallery` and display the first image file from each directory encountered on the way? Do the directories have anything in them other than image files?  What is the _first_ one? How are they sorted?  It would help if you posted a sample of the directories containing their files, and a list of what you would expect the output to be (which files)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski.
The folders contains only JPGs, the JPGs are in alphabetical order and all have a unique names.
folder(1) -> 2012-02-21 -> IMG_4534.JPG
folder(2) -> 2012-10-13 BlitZfestival (Hans) -> PIC_7112.JPG

Comment: Please always add clarifying info by editing the original question. It gets lost too easily in the comment thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain that each subdirectory only contains JPEG images, your `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` approach is a good start.  I'd stick with that, but to keep track of which directories you have already visited and displayed one image from, maintain an array which stores the *directory* portion of the filename, which you can easily get from [`pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_DIRNAME)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) or more simply from [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php).

The code below is tested and working on one of my directory trees of image files:

```
// Array to hold visited directories
// Each iteration will check this array for the
// current directory. If already present, it will be skipped
// and if not, action taken.
$visited_dirs = array();

$i = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(realpath('img/gallery'), RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
// Set the SKIP_DOTS flag to avoid '.' and '..'
// This method is available in PHP 5.3+
// $i->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
// Define the recursive iterator
$recursive = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($i);
// Loop over it
foreach ($recursive as $path => $object) {
  // Get the directory
  $dir = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

  // Only do something if this directory hasn't already been visited
  if (!in_array($dir, $visited_dirs)) {
    // Add to the list of visited dirs so it isn't used again
    $visited_dirs[] = $dir;

    // Do whatever you need to with the file for output
    // String manipulations, etc...
    $trimmed =  str_replace("/somestring/", "", $path);
    echo "<img src=".$trimmed." /></br>";
  }
}
```

#### On sorting:

Note that the above may not get you the sort you want. If you need to get them to sort alphabetically within subdirectories, you may store an array of all the files seen then `sort()` it, before looping over with similar array logic as above:

```
$visited_dirs = array();
// Array of all files
$all_files = array();
// $recurisve is the RecursiveIteratorIterator declared as
// in the first example
foreach ($recursive as $path => $object) {
  if ($object->isFile()) {
     // keep an array of all files
     $all_files[] = $path;
  } 
}
// Sort it
sort($all_files);

// Then loop and output just as in the last example
// but iterate the array
foreach ($all_files as $path) {
  $dir = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
  if (!in_array($dir, $visited_dirs)) {
    $visited_dirs[] = $dir;
    $trimmed =  str_replace("/somestring/", "", $path);
    echo "<img src=".$trimmed." /></br>";
  }
}
```

If you preferred, you could store all of the `$trimmed` values into another array rather than `echo` them directly in the loop. That would make it easier to use them all later. I would probably do it that way.

```
// Instead of directly echo...
$images[] = $trimmed;

// Later loop them to make use of them in a *different loop*
foreach ($images as $img) {
   echo "<img src='$img' alt='whatever' /></br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, 
If I want to run it, I get the error syntax error, unexpected '[' on $visited_dirs = [];

Comment: @Niles You must have PHP 5.3. To use array literals, PHP 5.4 is required. Instead use `$visited_dirs = array();` and the same for `$all_files = array();` if you use the second solution.

Comment: Sorry Michael, but my coding isn't that good. It's still not working:  Call to undefined method RecursiveDirectoryIterator::setFlags()

Comment: @Niles Ugh. That sounds like you are using PHP 5.2 because `setFlags()` is defined by the `FilesystemIterator` interface in 5.3.  Anyway, the solution to that is to just go back to setting the flag for SKIP_DOTS in the iterator's constructor. I edited it above.

Comment: @Niles If your host only supports PHP 5.2, you should really start looking to migrate to a better one. 5.2 has been unsupported for several years and is quite insecure, in addition to missing lots of great PHP features introduced in 5.3 & 5.4.

Comment: @Niles If you need to reply with another comment, please check back soon afterward. I am nearby for most of the day and will typically reply quickly.

Comment: ok, good to know. I changed it to 5.6. I thought that my hosting would use the newest php version...it was 5.3

Comment: @Niles Glad you are able to change it. This should work perfectly on 5.6 - please let me know if it does.

Comment: Thanks Michael It is almost working.
I can see the images, and I added my html as above.
But after image1, I get again image1 and image 2, and then again image1 and 2 and 3

Comment: @Niles Both my examples above are tested as working to output exactly one image from each dir only once.  A pattern like `1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4....` suggests a problem with the way you are appending to the `$images` array or a problem with how you are creating the string `$trimmed`. You would need to post more of your code.

Comment: you were absolutely right. I copied the exact code and it worked!
Is it possible too take this to another level??
I purchased a html template, in which I am now adding some php. Like this gallery. In this template the image is a link (added in question). Clicking the image will cause the image come to the front of the website, and now I can scroll through the images of $trimmed. Would it be possible when you click the image I could scroll through all images of the folder where the image is from (Do you understand what I am trying to say)

Comment: I asked a new question with some additional info http://stackoverflow.com/q/28003347/4267297

Comment: Coincidentally, I just saw it drop into the homepage stream.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28014841/4267297 rephrased question, because of some new thoughts