# Show all images from folder after selection one image out of an array

Tags: php

The code below create a image gallery, which shows all first images from different (sub)folders. Within the div arrows1 is some js to scroll trough those images.

The images are clickable links. Once clicked the photo, the image will come to the front of the webpage, and now I can also scroll trough the first images of all folders.

Is it possible to change that? Once the images is on the front I would like to scroll trough all images of that folder.
Folders have random names, and do not contain subfolders, and only contains images (jpegs)

```
$visited_dirs = array();

$i = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(realpath('img/gallerij'));
$i->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$recursive = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($i);
foreach ($recursive as $path => $object) {
  $dir = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

  if (!in_array($dir, $visited_dirs)) {
    $visited_dirs[] = $dir;

    $trimmed =  str_replace("/url/", "", $path);
?>
<ul class="list_4">
    <li>
        <div class="block_pic">
        <?php

        echo "<a href=".$trimmed."><img src=".$trimmed." alt=' '></a>";
        ?>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php
  }
}
?>


                    </div>
                    <div class="arrows1">
                    <a class="next1"><span></span></a>
                    <a class="prev1"><span></span></a>
                    </div>
```

This is the javascript which creates the popup and slideshow

```
if ($(".slider2").length) {
            $('.slider2').cycle({
                fx: 'scrollHorz',
                speed: 600,
                timeout: 0,
                next: '.next1',
                prev: '.prev1',
                easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
                cleartypeNoBg: true ,
                rev:0,
                startingSlide: 0,
                wrap: true
            })
        };
        var ind = 0;

        $('.arrows1 span').css({opacity:0});

        $('.next1').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('span').stop(true).animate({opacity:1}, 350, 'easeOutSine');
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('span').stop(true).animate({opacity:0}, 350, 'easeOutSine')
        })

        $('.prev1').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('span').stop(true).animate({opacity:1}, 350, 'easeOutSine');
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('span').stop(true).animate({opacity:0}, 350, 'easeOutSine')
});

$('.list_4 .block_pic > a').attr('rel','appendix')
.prepend('<span class="sitem_over"><strong></strong></span>')

$('.list_4 .block_pic > a').fancybox({
    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
    'transitionOut': 'elastic',
    'speedIn': 500,
    'speedOut': 300,
    'centerOnScroll': true,
    'overlayColor': '#000'
});

$('.list_4 .block_pic > a')
.find('strong').css('top','200px').end()
.hover(
    function(){
        if (!MSIE){
            $(this).children('.sitem_over').css({display:'block',opacity:'0'}).stop().animate({'opacity':1}).end()
            .find('strong').css({'opacity':0}).stop().animate({'opacity':1,'top':'0'},350,'easeInOutExpo');
        } else {
            $(this).children('.sitem_over').stop().show().end()
            .find('strong').stop().show().css({'top':'0'});
        }
    },
    function(){
        if (!MSIE){
            $(this).children('.sitem_over').stop().animate({'opacity':0},1000,'easeOutQuad',function(){$(this).children('.sitem_over').css({display:'none'})}).end()
            .find('strong').stop().animate({'opacity':0,'top':'200px'},1000,'easeOutQuad');
        } else {
            $(this).children('.sitem_over').stop().hide().end()
            .find('strong').stop().hide();
        }
    }
);
```

and this is the html from firebug of the popupped image

```
<div id="fancybox-content" style="border-width: 10px; width: 448px; height: 336px;">
<img id="fancybox-img" src="http://url/img/gallerij/folder/IMG_4795.JPG" alt="">
</div>
```

I hope I provided all the info the solve this question.
On request I can provide a link with the partly working webpage