# Show all images from dir when image clicked

Tags: php

With this code I pull the first image from multiple folders

```
<?php
$visited_dirs = array();

$i = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(realpath('img/gallerij'));
$i->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$recursive = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($i);
foreach ($recursive as $path => $object) {
  $dir = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

  if (!in_array($dir, $visited_dirs)) {
    $visited_dirs[] = $dir;

    $trimmed =  str_replace("/url/", "", $path);
?>
<ul class="list_4">
    <li>
        <div class="block_pic">
        <?php
        echo "<a href=".$trimmed."><img src=".$trimmed." alt=' '></a>";
        ?>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php
  }
}
?>
```

Now I would like to open the folder when clicked on the image
So probably I should do something with

```
<a href=".$trimmed.">
```

from

```
echo "<a href=".$trimmed."><img src=".$trimmed." alt=' '></a>";
```

Something like?

```
$dirname = "$dir";
$images = glob($dirname."*.JPG");
foreach($images as $image) {
//echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
echo "<a href=".$image."><img src=".$trimmed." alt=' '></a>";
}
```

Folders contains only JPG

Comment: What's the issue with what you have? What is it putting in the `href` or `src` attributes?

Comment: By "open the folder", do you mean to say you would load a new page entirely, which lists the images in the same directory as the one clicked?

Comment: Because then you could use something like `<a href='list_folder.php?folder=<?php echo dirname($trimmed); ?>'>...</a>` and in the script now called `list_folder.php` retrieve the folder name from `$_GET['folder']` and use a `glob()` for .JPG files like you suggest here.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I am not sure what you say, but I like to have all images of the same folder as the image I clicked on. 
The folder name is already in $dir from $visited_dirs[] = $dir;
And it is not a new page but a popup in the same page
I am trying some different thing but
I am afraid that you have to spell it out for me

Comment: @Niles If it is to be a popup in the current page, you will probably need an AJAX call from JavaScript back to PHP to get the listing of directories.